# How can I include jsp file which contains jsp and jstl tags in the custom tag

Tags: jsp, custom-tags

Is it possible to include .jsp file which contains jstl tags in the custom tag class(using tag files isn't an option in my particular case)?
For example I need to create custom tag to draw a table with the content of page scope variable. The table.jsp is:

```
<table>  
  <thead>  
    <tr>  
       <c:if test="${isAdmin }">  
          <th><fmt:message bundle="${prop}" key="orders.table.selected" /></th>  
       </c:if>  
    </tr> 
   more code here  
<table>
```

I tried to include this jsp using `pageContext.include()` method but I get all jstl tags on the html page

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include. `pageContext.include()` will inturn call `RequestDispatcher.include()`

Comment: calling  `pageContext.include()` just puts all jstl into html page without any changes